# Is there a good example for Spring cloud stream kafka binder for consuming generic json message

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am new to Spring cloud Stream and Kafka, I am looking for a good example for consuming json messages from a kafka topic.

Thanks

Comment: even though this is downvoted and marked as off topic, the answer to this solved my problem. I hate that this community is always focussing on closing and downvoting unimportant questions because they are such hardliner stack overflow members.
The point of stackoverflow is to help programmers and the answer to this helped me solve a problem I tried to solve for 5 hours or so...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can refer to the [examples from spring-cloud-stream team](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples) (sink & source projects)

To get the app running there are three scenarios.

If the consumer and producer are Spring-Cloud-Stream (SCS) apps, you just need to set the `content-type` as `application/json`.

```
#Specific channel
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.contentType=application/json
#For all channels
spring.cloud.stream.default.contentType=application/json
```

The second scenario is your producer is not a SCS and your consumer is a SCS, SCS by default add the headers embedded in the payload, so you need to disable that behavior putting `headerMode` as `raw` together with the `contentType`.

```
#Specific channel
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.headerMode=raw
#For all channels
spring.cloud.stream.default.consumer.headerMode=raw
```

In the third scenario is a SCS producer and not SCS consumer, In this case you need to use `application/octet-stream` as a `contentType` because SCS does not support raw headers for String ([there is a issue for that](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/855)), so you need to send the payload as bytes

```
#Properties
spring.cloud.stream.default.contentType=application/octet-stream
spring.cloud.stream.default.producer.headerMode=raw

//Java
byte[] payload = jacksonObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(entity);
return channel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload).build());
```